# Lists in NoSQL/BigTable Data Modeling & Super Columns (with Cassandra)

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cql

I'm new to NoSQL and BigTable, and I'm trying to learn how I can (and if should) use super columns to create a BigTable friendly schema.

Based on [this article](http://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) about NoSQL data modeling, it sounds like instead of using JOIN-centric RDBMS schemas, I should aggregate my data into larger tables to de-normalize where possible. Based on that, here's a simple schema I envisioned for a 'User', which I'm trying to create for Cassandra:

```
User: {
    KEY: UserId {
        name: {
           first, 
           last
        },
        age,
        gender
    }
};
```

The above column family (User), whose key is a 'UserID', is composed of 3 columns (name, age, gender.) Its column 'name' would be a super column who is composed of 'first' and 'last' columns.

**So what I'm asking is**:

1. <s>What does the [CQL 3.0](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql/CQL.html) look like to create this column family 'User' with the 'name' super column within it?</s> (**Update:** This doesn't appear possible.)
2. Should I be using super columns (like this)? Should I be using something else?
3. What's an alternative way of representing this schema?
4. How do I represent a list of values in a table/column family?

Here are some useful links about this that I found, but that I don't quite understand clearly enough to answer my question:

- [Create a Cassandra schema for a super column with metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298039/create-a-cassandra-schema-for-a-super-column-with-metadata)
- [Cassandra: How to create column in a super column family?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349417/cassandra-how-to-create-column-in-a-super-column-family)
- [Modeling relational data with Cassandra](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2010/10/modeling-relational-data-with-cassandra.html)

Thanks!

**Update:**

After alot of research, I'm learning a few things:

- You cannot create super columns using CQL; there might be other mechanisms to do so, but CQL does not appear to be one of them.
- Syntax for SQL 3.0 seems to be drifting from a 'COLUMN FAMILY'-centric approach towards SQL-like 'TABLE' based syntax.

Changed my questions accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I be using super columns (like this)? Should I be using
>   something else?

You can use that data model that you suggested. But generally it is not recommended for these reason as mentioned in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298039/create-a-cassandra-schema-for-a-super-column-with-metadata).

> I'll also note that use of super columns is generally discouraged as
>   they have  several disadvantages. All subcolumns in a super column
>   need to be deserialized  when reading one sub column and you can not
>   set secondary indexes on super  columns. They also only support one
>   level of nesting.

Hence consider these reasons for your situation.

> What's an alternative way of representing this schema?

You can try using composite columns. Read [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/introduction-to-composite-columns-part-1) for more information. Or you can probably just use standard column family, I think standard cf will be suitable for your situation. For example, following suggestion:

```
User : {
  key: userId {
    columnName:firstname
    ColumnName:lastname 
    ColumnName:age
    ColumnName:gender
    ColumnName:zip
    ColumnName:street
  }
  ..
};
```

> How do I represent a list of values in a table/column family?

It is possible to store the list in a BytesType in the cf. Or you can probably break the list into individual element and store as CompositeType.